# MariaDB (InnoDB) client disconnect release lock timeout

Tags: innodb, mariadb, locking

I have MariaDB (InnoDB). my client is setting lock on table.

In case he would fail for some random reason, what timeout setting I can set on the server, to release locks?

I know that DB discovers that client is disconnected and will release locks eventually, but after what time? Which setting is that?

I want lock, to prevent launching another "master" in the system, to avoid some work duplication in case of some bad devops settings. Singleton cluster pattern I would say.

Comment: "Master" and "Singleton cluster" -- Are you referring to Replication?  If so, please describe the topology of the servers.  If not, then re-word. "my client is setting lock on table" -- Show us the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that DB discovers that client is disconnected and will release locks eventually, but after what time? Which setting is that?

Table locks are associated with and held by the session that created the locks and will be released immediately when that session (i.e. connection) ends. The session could be terminated normally or unexpectedly, but the locks will be released regardless. The session/client could of course also release the locks sooner by executing [UNLOCK TABLES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/transactions-unlock-tables/).

I'm not sure there is any other way to unlock the tables, except you can of course set a timeout for how long a session can be inactive through [wait_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#wait_timeout) and [interactive_timeout](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#interactive_timeout). That way the tables will be unlocked as well.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder what you are trying to do, but below are the parameter for MariaDB Deadlock setting :

[innodb_lock_wait_timeout:
Timeout in seconds an InnoDB transaction may wait for a lock before being rolled back. The value 100000000 is infinite timeout.](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/innodb_lock_wait_timeout/)

[lock_wait_timeout :
Timeout in seconds to wait for a lock before returning an error.](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/lock_wait_timeout/)